# Set parent QWidget for promoted widgets

Tags: c++, qt, parent-child, qt-designer

I have a **Main** `QWidget` which contains three promoted widgets: **A** derived from `QGraphicsView`, **B** derived from `QLabel` and **C** derived from `QWidget`.
On application exit I need **B** and **C** to be destroyed before **A**, but I figured out that since **A**, **B** and **C** parent is automatically set to **Main**, **A** is destroyed first. This can be solved setting **A** as **B** and **C** parent.

The generated *ui_ProjectName.h* file has:

```
a = new A(Main);
b = new B(Main);
c = new C(Main);
```

But it should be:

```
a = new A(Main);
b = new B(a);
c = new C(a);
```

Is there a way to do this from Qt Designer directly to generate the correct *ui_ProjectName.h*?

Comment: Once you have the layout as you like, why can't you then edit the XML and swap around the order to suit ?

Comment: @SPlatten Because from Qt Creator when I switch to XML view it says "This file can only be edited in Design mode ."

Comment: Yes, I realise that, but there is nothing stopping you from opening the file outside of the IDE and editing the order, with a text editor.

Comment: @SPlatten Ok, then what changes should I do to the XML to make A the parent of B and C?

Comment: You would cut and paste them into the order that you want, I'm guessing that the order they are specified in the file is also the order in which they are constructed and destructed.

Comment: Dragging B and C into A body did it. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: no problem, glad you sorted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 3 widgets do not belong to same layout you can manually edit `.ui` file to assign proper parent to a widget. To make widget `A` a parent for a widget `B` you can just cut `<widget>` tag that belongs to `B` and paste it *inside* `A`'s `<widget>` tag. Like this:

```
<widget class="QWidget" name="A">
    <widget class="QWidget" name="B">
       ...
    </widget>
</widget>
```

Note that QtCreator has a legal way to edit `.ui` files: click right mouse button on `.ui` file and then choose "Open With -> Plain Text Editor".

But **pay attention**: this will break layout rules if you have them.
If you do not want to break layout for this case you probably can try reassign parents in runtime via code:

```
bWidget->setParent(aWidget);
cWidget->setParent(aWidget);
```

In this case it doesn't actually matter what code was generated in `ui_*.h` file — you will reset it.